# Why am I receiving an ArgumentException with this piece of code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Can anyone explain to me why I am receiving an `ArgumentException` from this piece of code? It's telling me that the `tasks` parameter in the `Task.WhenAll` function contains null values. However, it only happens every once in a while when I run it.

```
static async Task TestRequestSpeed()
{
    var requestTasks = new List<Task>();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 50, (i) =>
        {
            requestTasks.Add(HttpSocket.Instance.GetAsync("http://google.com"));
        });
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I don't understand how one of these requests would end up returning a null task. If someone could walk me through potential problems, I would appreciate it!

**Update:**

I should clarify that my intentions here are to make multiple requests in parallel to speed up execution. I'm working on a personal project that will need to make up to 200 requests in a single method call, and I was hoping to cut down on the time it takes to make those requests. Doing this with normal async-await procedures takes about 45 seconds at the moment, so I was hoping to make the requests in parallel to reduce that time down as much as possible. If there are better ways to do this, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it, but are you aware that you're missing a right parenthesis on that line?

    await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks).ConfigureAwait(

should be

    await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks).ConfigureAwait()

Comment: Is your `HttpSocket` threadsafe?

Comment: Why on earth are you putting the `requestTasks.Add` into a `Parallel.For`? You gain NOTHING from doing that, the actual code should be slower, and the point of `GetAsync` is you are doing `I/O async`. Thread parallelization will only slow things down.

Comment: @Aron What I'm going for is making multiple requests in parallel. I'm working on a personal project and I'm trying to learn how I can make multiple requests at the same time to speed up the execution. Normal async-await gives me unsatisfactory performance. Should I be doing synchronous requests inside the `Parallel.ForEach` block?

Comment: No you are wrong. You are making threads to send off requests. But the process of context switching is slow. Sending requests is fast, so doing it in sequence is faster.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if it's taking me 45 seconds to make 200 requests, there's no way for me to reduce that time down to something like 20 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal `List<T>` is not thread safe. And you are `Add`ing from potentially 50 parallel threads. That won't work.

Either insert into that list sequentially, or use a container that is thread safe for adding.

Comment: More to the point initializing 50 I/O async operations does not require thread parallelization.

Comment: This is indeed the reason for the exception I was having. Many thanks for helping me out with this. I'm just getting me feet wet with asynchronous programming and multithreading so a lot of things, like thread-safe containers, are still foreign to me.

Answer (score 4):

There is definitely no good reason to use multiple threads to initialize a list of tasks. The overhead is more than the gain. You can use `Enumerable.Select` instead:

```
static async Task TestRequestSpeedAsync()
{
   var requestTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(HttpSocket.Instance.GetAsync("http://www.google.com"));

   await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Note i added the `Async` postfix to follow the TAP guidelines.

Comment: I guess what I was going for was to make multiple requests in parallel. Would I be better of doing synchronous work inside the `Parallel.ForEach`? I was under the impression that doing it this way would allow the tasks to follow normal async-await procedure while also doing so on separate threads in parallel.

Comment: @xCrispy Normal async behavior means there are no extra threads. It means we use the async nature of IO bound work. You use `Parallel.Foreach` only to add the operation to a list. That is completely unnecessary.

Comment: So, again, would I be better off doing synchronous work inside that `Parallel.ForEach` instead of just using it to add a task to a list? Would it make more sense to do `HttpSocket.Instance.Get("http://google.com")` inside it?

Comment: No. IO bound operations need not use Threads. Your `Parallel.ForEach` is redundant, you dont need it **at all**

Comment: Oh okay. Now it's clicking for me. The only time I should use the TPL is when I'm doing CPU-bound operations that would benefit from multithreading.

Comment: Most likely, yes. You're getting the hang of it. Of course you'll find cases when the TPL will be useful with async-await, but for most cases your comment is on the rightous path

Answer (score 1):

As nvoigt says, `List<T>` cannot support being written to by multiple threads. Luckily .net already includes a set of collections that support thread-safe writes under the `System.Collections.Concurrent` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

As an example this seems to work for me:

```
static async Task TestRequestSpeed()
{
    var requestTasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Task>();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 50, (i) =>
        {
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            requestTasks.Enqueue(hc.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://google.com")));
        });
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```